# Construction of uncountably many non-isomorphic linear (total) orderings of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, natural-numbers

I would like to find a way to construct uncountably many non-isomorphic linear (total) orderings of natural numbers (as stated in the title).

I've already constructed two non-isomorphic total orderings. They are
$$
1 < 2 < 3 <\ldots\\
1 > 2 > 3 >\ldots
$$
where "$<$" and "$>$" are  strict total ordering relations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** If you just want "uncountably many", then it's easy to observe that each countable ordinal can be expressed as a linear order of $\Bbb N$.

However if you want $2^{\aleph_0}$ (which is the maximal number of orders), then given $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, it is possible to use $A$ to define a unique linear order which looks like copies of the rational numbers with finite intervals between them, whose size depends on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You can partition $\mathbb{N}$ into infinite subsets $S_1$, $S_2$...., and place $S_2$ after $S_1$, $S_3$ after $S_2$ ..... where each $S_i$ is ordered exactly the same way as the natural order or its reverse($<$ or $>$). There are uncountably many partitions of $\mathbb{N}$, so there are uncountably many nonisomorphic linear orderings.